# Dynamic change not occurring in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit rusty on my java-script(jQuery) but I'm trying to add a feature on my webpage. The script steps through, but the value is not updated on the page. I am probably forgetting something minor but not finding it in searching for it.

The following html is generated on my web page

```
<div class="panel-body">
     Great job on this vintage piece of machinery!
     <br />
     <span id="thumbs">                                        
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-vote="up" data-id=1 value="up">&#128077;</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a  href="javascript:void(0)" data-vote="down" data-id=1 value="down">&#128078;</a>
    </span>
    <span class="likedisplay">
         Likes&nbsp;<span id="upvotes"><strong>27</strong></span>
         &nbsp;
         DisLikes&nbsp;<span id="downvotes"><strong>6</strong></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is the script.

```
 $("#thumbs a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var commentId = $(this).data("id");
        var vote = $(this).data("vote");
        increment(vote, commentId);

    });
    function increment(vote, commentId) {
        if (vote === "up") {
            //call the database to increase the like count for this comment
             //IncrementLikes(commentId);
            $("#upvotes").val(parseInt($("#upvotes").val()) + 1);
            toastr.info("Your Like was posted!");
        }
        if (vote === "down") {
            //call the database to increase the like count for this comment
             // IncrementDisLikes(commentId);
            $("#downvotes").val(parseInt($("#downvotes").val()) + 1);
            toastr.info("Your DisLike was posted!");
        }
    }
```

$("#upvotes").val steps through fine but does not update the value on the page. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.`text()`instead of `val()` is needed because you are dealing with `span`. `val()` applied to `input fields`.

2.`$("#upvotes strong")` needed instead of `$("#upvotes")` there (same for `downvotes` too).

3.`data-id="1"` is correct way instead of `data-id=1`

***Working code:-***

```js
$("#thumbs a").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var commentId = $(this).data("id");
  var vote = $(this).data("vote");
  increment(vote, commentId);
});

function increment(vote, commentId) {
  if (vote === "up") {
    $("#upvotes strong").text(parseInt($("#upvotes strong").text()) + 1);
    toastr.info("Your Like was posted!");
  }
  if (vote === "down") {
    $("#downvotes strong").text(parseInt($("#downvotes strong").text()) + 1);
    toastr.info("Your DisLike was posted!");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  Great job on this vintage piece of machinery!
  <br />
  <span id="thumbs">                                        
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-vote="up" data-id="1" value="up">&#128077;</a>&nbsp;
    <a  href="javascript:void(0)" data-vote="down" data-id="1" value="down">&#128078;</a>
  </span>
  <span class="likedisplay">
    Likes&nbsp;<span id="upvotes"><strong>27</strong></span>&nbsp;
    DisLikes&nbsp;<span id="downvotes"><strong>6</strong></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The data-id is generated dynamically, thus no quote. Ill figure out how to add the quotations.

Comment: @dinotom  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `text()` method instead of `val()` because the element is a `<span>`, not `<input>`.

also you need to do `$("#upvotes").find('strong').text()` to keep formatting.

P.S: I suggest using CSS instead of `<strong>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that you need to pay attention:

1) The attributes. You have used

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-vote="up" data-id=1 value="up">
```

For correctness, please add attribute values between double quotes `"` which leads to the following fix

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-vote="up" data-id="1" value="up">
```

2) be aware which function you are using. You have used jQuery's [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function which only works on `<input>` elements, not other elements. The jQuery documentation even mentions it:

> The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`. When called on an empty collection, it returns `undefined`. [source](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

You have used that function on a non-input element. To retrieve the content of a non-input element, please use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or put the values in an input element.

Here is a fixed and working code (I've replaced the toastr message to console.log)

```js
 $("#thumbs a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var commentId = $(this).data("id");
        var vote = $(this).data("vote");
        increment(vote, commentId);

    });
    function increment(vote, commentId) {
        if (vote === "up") {
            //call the database to increase the like count for this comment
             //IncrementLikes(commentId);
            $("#upvotes").text(parseInt($("#upvotes").text()) + 1);
            console.log("Your Like was posted!");
        }
        if (vote === "down") {
            //call the database to increase the like count for this comment
             // IncrementDisLikes(commentId);
            $("#downvotes").text(parseInt($("#downvotes").text()) + 1);
            console.log("Your DisLike was posted!");
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
     Great job on this vintage piece of machinery!
     <br />
     <span id="thumbs">                                        
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-vote="up" data-id="1" value="up">&#128077;</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a  href="javascript:void(0)" data-vote="down" data-id="1" value="down">&#128078;</a>
    </span>
    <span class="likedisplay">
         Likes&nbsp;<span id="upvotes"><strong>27</strong></span>
         &nbsp;
         DisLikes&nbsp;<span id="downvotes"><strong>6</strong></span>
    </span>
</div>
```